# Using value object as identifier in entity

Tags: entity, domain-driven-design, value-objects

While viewing Evans' project on sample DDD project, I notice that in the `Cargo` entity, Evans uses tracknumber which is an value object. Why he didn't chooses plain `string tracknumber` instead chooses value object for identity? Here is snippet from Evans:

```
public class Cargo implements Entity<Cargo> {

  private TrackingId trackingId
}

public final class TrackingId implements ValueObject<TrackingId> {

  private String id;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * @param id Id string.
   */
  public TrackingId(final String id) {
    Validate.notNull(id);
    this.id = id;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things that would achieve:

- Encapsulates the logic that the Tracking ID should not be null
- Encapsulates the logic that the Tracking ID should not change once set.

With a plain string, the Cargo object would have to be aware of these rules.  Using the Value Object approach means the TrackingId maintains these rules about itself.

Comment: We can achieve the same in .Net world , we have readonly variable  which is set only through constructor and cannot be changed later or only having getter no setter ,.

Comment: Sure, but then the logic would be in the Cargo object, not in the TrackingId.  The point I was making is the Value Object approach encapsulates that logic in the Tracking Id itself.

Comment: @kamal. The TrackingId would also be able to do other useful things that the Cargo object doesn't need or want to know about, like formatting itself on a customer inquiry, assigning the next available id number, and other tricky logic that more than justifies it's existence. Cheers